# Gigya swift sdk login with social providers getting issue: [facebook] can't login with WebView, install related sdk

Tags: swift, gigya

```
Gigya.sharedInstance().showScreenSet(with:"Store-RegistrationLogin", viewController: self) { result in
            switch result {
            case .onLogin(let account):
                // onLogin event
                print("onLoginaccount-->",account)
            case .error(let event):
                // error event
                print("error-->",event)
            case .onAfterValidation(event: let event):
                print("onAfterValidation")
            case .onCanceled:
                print("onCanceled")
            }
        }
```

i am using above code Gigya screen set is loaded and Normal registration and login working fine but when i click on the Social providers App crash i am getting below issue
[facebook] can't login with WebView, install related sdk. curently i am using xcode 13.1 and swift 5
Please help me @thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstable following the instruction from Facebook:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

once you have it works, following our instructions:
https://sap.github.io/gigya-swift-sdk/GigyaSwift/#facebook

You can find our providers wrappers here:
https://github.com/SAP/gigya-swift-sdk/releases/tag/core%2Fv1.3.1

Do not forget to configurate your provider in your console:
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_CUSTOMER_DATA_CLOUD/8b8d6fffe113457094a17701f63e3d6a/5ff3bc8174da4542a61d03033af4877d.html

Comment: Above steps working fine @ Thank you @@ Sagi Shmuel

Comment: Please send me steps how to get TwitterWrappers from Gigya Provides ,above links Apple, Facebook, Google all gigya providers there ,but i need login with Twitter account .@Thanks

Comment: there is no instructions for Twitter, you needs to do it like in web.

Comment: Thanks for your replaying , first time i login with twitter working fine i got the login account details but i going to registration page now i click on the same twitter icon(login) i am getting the error code : 400002 , error: Missing required params call back functions not working , "showScreenset" page not loaded Please explain steps @@Thanks

Comment: You have implementation issue, please open a ticket with your CS/PS, this is the best practice for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Facebook native login to your iOS app is mandatory if you want to login via Facebook. https://sap.github.io/gigya-swift-sdk/GigyaSwift/#facebook

Comment: i installed below pods and FacebookApp id and Url schemes aded my project info list  but i am not able to login or registration throught facebook
  pod 'FacebookSDK'
  pod 'FacebookSDK/LoginKit'
  pod 'FacebookSDK/ShareKit'
  pod 'FacebookSDK/PlacesKit'
  pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'
Please send me steps  @Thanks